# How to run old STS 2.8.0 GWT SDK project in new STS 3.7.2?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, spring-tool-suite

I unfortunately happened to have to fix an old project written by somebody else long ago. All they left were brief instructions regarding what IDE did they use and what configurations to select to compile.

I have the old STS version they used and the project can be launched in it. The problem is that the IDE is incredibly laggy and erroneous. It randomly crashes on memory exceptions, needs me to clean and rebuild often as it messes up builds, randomly not compiles java classes and so on. I want to try whether they improved at least some of that over the years.

I downloaded the new STS. I backed up my workspace, fortunately, because of course new STS also messes up things as I quickly learned. This is the menu I used to launch the project from old STS:

[image: image description]

New STS deleted the items:
[image: image description]

The IDE instructions for the project state that the the GWT should added using *Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Google* -> *Web Toolkit*. You guessed it, it's not there:

[image: image description]

How to run GWT project in new STS IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like someone installed the GWT plugin for Eclipse into the old STS installation and you don't have that yet in the new STS installation. I would recommend to take a look at: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/ to get instructions on that extension of Eclipse.

I am sure there is also an item on the STS Dashboard Extension install to easily grab the Google Plugin and install it into your STS version.

Aside of that I would be interested in hearing more details about what exactly the latest STS version is messing up. Please let us know the details behind your projects so that we are able to fix them for the next version. A simple "of course new STS also messes up things as I quickly learned" doesn't help much. Would appreciate more details and reports about that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: *of course new STS also messes up things as I quickly learned* was specifically referencing to deleted launch history - which seems to be due to missing google plug-in. Please understand that I wrote this after a week of consistent frustration by both the IDE and the under-documented project. The reason I did download the new version was because I do believe the developers are making improvements.

Comment: I totally understand your frustration and would like to help with that in two ways. First by thinking about steps how to get things to work now and as a second step how to improve STS in order to avoid this in the future. The Google Plugin is not really part of STS, so there isn't much we can do about that implementation, but nevertheless if there is anything we can do to improve STS, please let me know. I would be very happy to hear about it and incorporate improvements in upcoming releases.